# How can i add relate table to not related table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have `Order`, `Product` and `CartLine`. That is a sturcture:

Order.cs

`public IQueryable<CartLine> Lines { get; set; }`

CartLine.cs

```
public class CartLine {
        public int CartLineID { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Product.cs

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }
```

So that a question, how can i take Product in CartLine from db. Need to use information about product from cartline.

I did somehow like this `Orders.Include("Product")` , but Orders haven't this property so i got a exception. How may i do this, or i need to rewrite the structure?

UPD Get exception:

> The property 'Product' is not a navigation property of entity type 'Order'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `Orders.Include(Product)` and not `Orders.Include("Product")`?

Comment: Point not in this. Update question with Exception.

Comment: You need the same instance of the database class db in all modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to go with the strongly typed `Include` methods where possible.

If your using standard EF:

```
Orders.Include(o => o.Lines.Select(l => l.Product));
```

Using EF Core:

```
Orders.Include(o => o.Lines).ThenInclude(l => l.Product);
```

Your issue is that "Product" is not a property of `Order` it is a property of `CartLine`, which would have been more apparent using the strongly typed methods.

If you do need to use `Include(string)` you can do it like this:

```
Orders.Include("Lines.Product");
```

Comment: Yeah thats work, i'm actually try to used ThenInclude, but it didn't work, but now it's work, Thanks a lot!